# Find date when and ear or jar was built without original source code

Tags: java, jar, ear

I have inherited a Java project with quite a bit of history in the GIT repository. I have also inherited an ear allegedly built from this repository. I would like to determine which branch and commit this ear corresponds to in my GIT repository. I suspect I can narrow this down by using the date the ear or any of its contained jars were built. How can I find the date when an ear and or the jars it contains was built?

Comment: Ears and jars are just zip files so any zip editor should be able to show you the file dates.

Comment: Thanks Thomas that worked.